Opposite conclusions from Chi-Square and logistic regression
I have two main variables of interest:
V1: Whether people picked choice A or choice B
V2: Whether people were in group X or group Y
Both are coded 0 and 1.
I also have continuous control variables.
When computing a crosstab with both variables (V1 & V2), I observe that people in group Y have a higher frequency of choosing A compared to choosing B compared to people in group X.
Pearson's Chi-Square test comes out significant.
Fictitious illustration below:
     V1_A V1_B
V2_X   75   25
V2_Y   85   15

When I perform a logistic regression with both variables (V1 ~ V2), the intercept comes out significant with an OR < 1.
This is in line with the crosstab: people have a higher chance of choosing A (coded 0) than B (coded 1) across both values of V2.
However, the effect of V2 also comes out significant, but the OR is ≈2 - meaning that people have a higher chance of choosing B over A in group Y compared to group X.
This seems to go against the conclusions from the crosstab, and this effect holds even when I'm introducing continuous control variables in the model.
Assuming there is no coding error, how can this discrepancy be explained?
I have a feeling that, as for many statistical procedures, conclusions can vary as they do not look and answer at the same questions - but I cannot quite get the specific reason why this could be the case here.

Can you show the  detailed summary of your logistic regression and chi-squared test? I tried with the example you gave, and I don't reach at all the same results and conclusions as you. Perhaps there's something I've been missing in your description, but it would be much easier to identify where we disagree if you share more details.

The analyses were performed using SPSS. For the logistic regression, Y was inadvertently set as the reference category for V2 rather than X. Of course, this changed the direction of the effect.
Because this error went unnoticed, the OR was mistakenly interpreted as a higher chance of choosing B over A in group Y compared to group X. However, with Y as the reference category, the OR correctly indicates a higher chance of choosing B over A in group X.
Therefore, there is no discrepancy between the contingency table and the logistic regression.
The only issue was with trusting that no one made a syntaxing error before posting the question!

It's not a syntax error. Different programs, and different functions within programs, have different rules about how they code variables. It's an understanding error.
